# Клонирование объектов в Java

Tags: java

Есть класс `Person` :

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private int age;
    private Car car;

    public Person(final String name, final int age, final Car car) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.car = car;
    }

    public Person(final Person person){
        this(person.getName(), person.getAge(), person.getCar());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", car=" + car +
                '}';
    }
}
```

как создать клон объекта этого класса так, чтобы у клона был создан новый объект класса `Car` ? Заранее спасибо за ответ ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В копирующем конструкторе `Person` заменить `person.getCar()` на вызов копирующего конструктора `Car`.

```
public Person(final Person person){
    this(person.getName(), person.getAge(), new Car(person.getCar()));
}
```

Разумеется, конструктор `public Car(Car car)` должен быть реализован.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, действительно работает)